# Using .htaccess to implement clean urls in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My homepage is set to

```
 /localhost/HobbyClub/index.php
```

and I want to set it to

```
 /localhost/HobbyClub/home
```

which is basically implementing clean URL.

I tried 2 different codes :

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost/HobbyClub$
RewriteRule ^(.*) localhost/HobbyClub/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php [L]
```

AND

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /home [L]
```

Both did not work. After this, I also want to be able implement :

```
localhost/HobbyClub/club.php?id=1
```

redirecting to

```
localhost/HobbyClub/club/Architecture
```

I went through a lot of answers here on StackOverflow but just couldn't implement this myself.

Comment: for starters is mod_rewrite enabled on your server.

Comment: Yes. Checked that as well as .conf file. Restarted apache and all of that.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost/HobbyClub$` – that is nonsense, because `localhost/HobbyClub` is not a host name. (And it is quite unclear whether you mean it to be a folder name or the host name in your example URLs, so please clarify.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in `/HobbyClub/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /HobbyClub/

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Still not working.

'AllowOverride All' is mentioned in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

mod_rewrite is also enabled.

What else should I check?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not while visiting `http://localhost/HobbyClub/home`

Comment: So, /localhost/HobbyClub/home is working. But my home link is still set to 'index.php'. So everytime I click home, it still shows up as '/index.php'. What am I supposed to mention in the home link now? Or do I need to write a redirect condition?

Comment: Yes you should change your link's href to `/HobbyClub/home`

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please help me a little more?

 I also want to be able to implement : 
localhost/HobbyClub/club.php?id=1 redirecting to localhost/HobbyClub/club/Architecture